# jquery to change style attribute of a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider class like this and I wan to change the style attribute **style="left: 336px"**

```
<div id="range-cont">
<div class="slider">
<div class="progress" style="width: 350px;"></div>
    <a class="handle" href="#" **style="left: 336px;"**></a>
</div>
<input id="percentage" class="range" type="range" value="14" name="percentage" min="0" max="100">
<p id="percent-label">%</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried 
`$('.handle').css({'style':'left: 300px'})` but its not working. 
Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Just try `$('.handle').css('left', '300px');`

Answer (score 101):

if you just want to set the style attribute use

```
$('.handle').attr('style','left: 300px');
```

Or you can use css method of jQuery to set only one css style property

```
$('.handle').css('left', '300px');
```

OR same as key value

```
$('.handle').css({'left': '300px'});
```

[More info on W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Comment: this is a more complete and better answer than the one selected

Comment: `$('.handle').prop('style','left: 300px');` is working too

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.handle').css('left', '300px');

$('.handle').css({
    left : '300px'
});

$('.handle').attr('style', 'left : 300px');
```

or use OrnaJS

Answer (score 8):

Try with

```
$('.handle').css({'left': '300px'});
```

Or

```
$('.handle').css('left', '300px');
```

Instead of

```
$('.handle').css({'style':'left: 300px'})
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('.handle').css('left','300px')` try this, identificator first then the value

more on this here:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

this helpful for you..

```
$('.handle').css('left', '300px');
```

Answer (score 2):

Style is an attribute so `css` won't work for it.U can use `attr`

Change:

```
$('.handle').css({'style':'left: 300px'});
```

T0:

```
$('.handle').attr('style','left: 300px');//Use `,` Comma instead of `:` colon
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use
 `$('#Id').attr('style',' color:red');`
and 
    `$('#Id').css('padding-left','20%');`
at the same time.
You can either use `attr` *or* `css` but both only works when they are used alone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the attribute of the class conditionally,

```
var css_val = $(".handle").css('left');
if(css_val == '336px')
{
  $(".handle").css('left','300px');
}
```

If id is given as following,

```
<a id="handle" class="handle" href="#" style="left: 336px;"></a>
```

Here is an alternative solution:

```
var css_val = $("#handle").css('left');
if(css_val == '336px')
{
  $("#handle").css('left','300px');
}
```