# HTML Elements in jQuery and CSS styling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet, element

I am known to HTML and CSS. Now I am trying to learn jQuery. I want to know how to make a DIV in jQuery and then style it with CSS in jQuery?

I have searched alot on google but cant find any help there. I hope you can help me.

Everything from make a DIV and then styling it should only be done in jQuery. I dont want to use HTML at all.

Thanks

Comment: Creating a div in jquery:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery][1]

Style your div in jquery:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581763/jquery-to-change-style-attribute-of-a-div-class][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581763/jquery-to-change-style-attribute-of-a-div-class

Comment: So its like you want to create a < div > tag and you don't want to mention < div > anywhere. ???

Comment: Make a DIV with only using jQuery, not HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample attaches a div to the parent container, and adds some css styling to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var theNewDiv = $("<div id='mydiv'>").appendTo("body");
  theNewDiv.css({"height": "100px", "width": "100px", "background-color":"blue"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I actually need everything to be done in jQuery, without using HTML...?

Comment: You can create a div using jQuery and style it, but you still need a valid HTML container to attach your div, even if it is just $("body").append("<div>");

Comment: You can attach it to BODY?

Comment: Yes you can, $("body").append() method should work.

Comment: Could you please show me with the help of snippet?

Comment: Done... I used appendTo() method instead, because it is easier to get a handle to the new div via the return variable. But moth append() and appendTo() achieve the same result.

Comment: This looks better. Is it possible to give ID to a DIV? Just as HTML...

Comment: Yes, you can add the id attribute directly to the new jQuery object, as shown in the modified example.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#divid").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
</script>

<div id="divid">This is a paragraph.</div>
```

Comment: This is a paragraph, I am looking for DIV my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below is what you are looking at,
**first Jquery is not a replacement for html**
but you can manipulate html DOM elements.
As an example you can add html elements to another element.
I took below code from another SO answer.
First select the parent element with something like

$("#id"), $("element") or $(".class")

Then use the .append("< div >foo< /div >") function. Alternatively, you can use the .html()

$("#foo").append("< div > hello world < /div  >")